# Upload image to c# server from iPhone

Tags: c#, iphone, asp.net, iis, http-post

I want to upload a image to my server form iPhone 
To upload image my code is

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_DName.png"];
NSMutableData *imageData  = (NSData*)UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

     NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myServer/HeritageWebServices/Service.asmx/testuploadimage"];

    [self setRequest1:[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]]];
    [request1 setPostValue:@"test" forKey:@"value1"];
    [request1 setPostValue:@"test" forKey:@"value2"];
    [request1 setPostValue:@"test" forKey:@"value3"];
    [request1 setTimeOutSeconds:20];
    [request1 setDelegate:self];
    [request1 setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadFailed:)];
    [request1 setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadFinished:)];
    [request1 setPostBody:imageData];


//    NSLog(@"image %@",imageData);
   [request1 setData:imageData withFileName:@"photo.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"photo"];
[request1 startAsynchronous];
```

With the above code i am not able upload image.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
    NSData *imageData  = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    //NSLog(@"imageData %@",imageData);
    NSString *dt = [[imageData description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:     
                    [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]]; 
    dt = [dt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myServer/HeritageWebServices/Service.asmx/testuploadimage?image=%@",dt];
   // NSLog(@"urlstring %@",string);
      request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]];
    //    
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

If i try like this i can upload small image but not large images.Here i am sending the image  in the request parameter as string.

My c# code to receive image

```
[WebMethod]
       public byte[] testuploadimage(string image)
       {
           byte[] imageBytes;
           System.Net.HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://myServer/HeritageWebServices/Service.asmx/testuploadimage");
           httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
           httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
           httpWebRequest.ContentLength = image.Length;

           XmlDocument login = new XmlDocument();
           XmlDeclaration dec = login.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
           login.AppendChild(dec);
           XmlElement root = login.CreateElement("CreateUser");
           login.AppendChild(root);

           //try
           //{

               string actFolder = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
               string s = image.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

               ErrLogMgr.LogErrorMessage(string.Format("{0}{1}", "testuploadimage() for the image :",
                                                      image), "testUploadimage Inputs",
                                                       ERRORSOURCE.CSASERVICE);
               string imgname = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString().Replace(" ", "").Replace("AM", "").Replace("PM", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("-", "").Replace(":", "") + ".png";
               //       string imgname = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + ".png";

               //  byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(image.Replace(" ","+"));
               imageBytes = HexStringToByteArray(s);
               MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
               // MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
               // Convert byte[] to Image
               //  ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
               ErrLogMgr.LogErrorMessage(string.Format("{0}{1}", "testuploadimage() for the image :",
                                                      image), "testUploadimage Inputs",
                                                       ERRORSOURCE.CSASERVICE);

               Image image2 = Image.FromStream(ms);
               ErrLogMgr.LogErrorMessage(string.Format("{0}{1}", "testuploadimage() for the image :",
                                                      image), "testUploadimage Inputs",
                                                       ERRORSOURCE.CSASERVICE);
               // System.Drawing.Bitmap image2 =  new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms);
               image2.Save(actFolder + imgname);


               XmlElement root1 = login.CreateElement("uploaded");
               root1.InnerText = "true";
               root.AppendChild(root1);
               XmlElement root2 = login.CreateElement("path");
               root2.InnerText = "http://myServer/HeritageWebServices/Images/" + imgname;
               root.AppendChild(root2);

              // return login;
               return imageBytes;

          // }
           //catch (Exception ex)
           //{
           //    ErrLogMgr.LogErrorMessage(string.Format("{0}{1}", "testuploadimage() for the image :",
           //                                           image), "testUploadimage Inputs",
           //                                            ERRORSOURCE.CSASERVICE);
           //    XmlDocument cd = new XmlDocument();
           //    cd.LoadXml("<Message>" + ex + "</Message>");
           //   // return cd;
           //    return imageBytes;
           //}


       }


       private byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string hexString) 
       {
           int bytesCount = (hexString.Length) / 2;
           byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesCount];

           for (int x = 0; x < bytesCount; ++x)
           {
               bytes[x] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16);
           }

           return bytes;
       } 
   }
```

For the large image exception which i am getting on server is

System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+. at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams) at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format) at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename) at Heritage.Service.testuploadimage(String image) –

Can anybody help me.. What am i doing wrong
Is the problem with my iPhone code of with my c# code.
Thanx!!!

Comment: You need to add what exception you're getting on the server or the error on the client.  Also, does the server code even get hit?  Trace, log, attach, something ...

Comment: This is the exception i am getting if i upload large image file System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+. at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams) at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format) at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename) at Heritage.Service.testuploadimage(String image)

Comment: @SurenderRathore - Update your question with the exception.  Sounds like the problem is with the server side code.

Comment: yep, looks like a server side issue (config).  see my answer

Answer (score 0):

0x80004005 translates to access denied.  So, it looks like it's server side config.

Look at the permissions on the path you are trying to save the image as.  Also ensure the appPool identity or the end user has write permissions (depends on your asp.net security configuration/delegation settings).

Comment: Thanx for reply...this exception only occurs if i send large image.. what should i do to resolve this..